# python mysql operationalerror

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python script that processes some data and then inserts it into mysql using [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/).

When I run the script on my local server all is well. When I run it on our server I straightaway get

```
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the logs of your MySQL installation and see if it is really gone and for whatever reason.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

changed hosting provider and problem went away. Must have been configured poorly.

Comment: This doesn't help anyone who finds the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`2006, 'MySQL server has gone away'` means time out. Most times when it happend to me when I try to connet to external mysql server and this server was not set up to accept external connections (from your localhost). Straightaway response would confirm it.

Comment: note that I am running the script on the server where mysql is local

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs of your MySQL installation and see if it is really gone and for whatever reason. Apart from that check your network connectivity and the network configuration of mysqld (it must listen on the related external network addresses). Not a Python issue.